# How to match a variable to an array without index but with keys of different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-pair

I am trying to match a variable value with a response from API in pure javascript. For matching, I have taken static index from the response but later on, there might be a scenario where the index changes. So I have another array of fields that stores the exact position.

Is there a way to use this array to match the variable value?
Here is the response with two arrays one with field keys and another is data array.

```
 "fields":[
      "date",
      "energy",
      "impact-e",
      "lat",
      "lat-dir",
      "lon",
      "lon-dir",
      "alt",
      "vel"
   ],
   "data":[
      [
         "2018-12-18 23:48:20",
         "3133",
         "49",
         "56.9",
         "N",
         "172.4",
         "E",
         "26.0",
         "13.6"
      ],
      [
         "2020-12-22 23:23:33",
         "489.8",
         "9.5",
         "31.9",
         "N",
         "96.2",
         "E",
         "35.5",
         "13.6"
      ],
      ....many more
]
```

The condition which I am trying to use to match the data is:

```
 if (
      response[i][4] === latDir &&
      response[i][6] === longDir &&
      Number(response[i][3]) >= latMinVal &&
      Number(response[i][3]) <= latMaxVal &&
      Number(response[i][5]) >= longMinVal &&
      Number(response[i][5]) <= longMaxVal
    ) {
  // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Is there a way to make it less dependent on the index of the data array and make it reliable on the fields array?

Comment: since your data array has only values and no keys, you have to use the index. a better approach would be to modify the api (if its yours) to send key and value. then you could map the data in a more efficient way.

Comment: So go find what index position `lat-dir` is at in your `fields` array - then you know what index to use to access the corresponding item within your data arrays. And same for the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const infos = 
  { fields: 
    [ 'date', 'energy', 'impact-e', 'lat', 'lat-dir', 'lon', 'lon-dir', 'alt', 'vel'] 
  , data: 
    [ [ '2018-12-18 23:48:20', '3133',  '49', '56.9',  'N', '172.4', 'E', '26.0', '13.6'] 
    , [ '2020-12-22 23:23:33', '489.8', '9.5', '31.9', 'N', '96.2', 'E', '35.5', '13.6'] 
    ] 
  // , ...
  } 

const kp = infos.fields.reduce((keysPairs,c,i)=>{keysPairs[c]=i; return keysPairs},{})
/*
kp = 
  { 'date'     : 0
  , 'energy'   : 1
  , 'impact-e' : 2
  , 'lat'      : 3
  , 'lat-dir'  : 4
  , 'lon'      : 5
  , 'lon-dir'  : 6
  , 'alt'      : 7
  , 'vel'      : 8
  } 
*/

for (let response of infos.data)
  {
  if ( response[kp['lat-dir']]    === latDir 
    && response[kp['lon-dir']]    === longDir 
    && Number(response[kp['lat']]) >= latMinVal 
    && Number(response[kp['lat']]) <= latMaxVal 
    && Number(response[kp['lon']]) >= longMinVal 
    && Number(response[kp['lon']]) <= longMaxVal
    ) {
    // do something
    }
  // ...
  }
```